How can I stream using the AMF encoder on OBS on Kubuntu 24.04 LTS?
I'm a complete Linux newbie here, so sorry if I'm missing any pertinent information. I'll keep my eyes on this thread to answer any questions or supply any additional information needed!
Basically exactly what the title says. I can't seem to get the AMF encoder to show up in OBS on my Kubuntu 24.04 LTS install. To the best of my knowledge, it seems I have the necessary components and drivers from AMD for my 6950XT to utilize it, but the setting simply doesn't show up when I'm in OBS. I've watched a few tutorials on how to get AMF to appear, but those were outdated and for other distros. Is there perhaps an argument I need to change for OBS to detect/launch with it, or maybe another driver set I should try?
Lastly, my apologies if this is posted somewhere and I just missed it! Feel free to point me there, and I'll get working on it.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].
